# SQLite - Match results based on string value issue

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm currently having an issue with my SQL Lite code with regards to counting matching results. In my application the user will have the ability to add a new folder and give it a name. Before the folder is added to the application my code will check to see if a folder with the same name already exists if so it will prompt the user.

When using my code below I receive an error informing me the column doesn't exist. If I remove everything past WHERE then it works perfectly and counts every record within the table.

I've reinstalled the application and changed the database version so that its completely clean, just to make sure. I'm certain its only something very minor I'm missing.

```
public int countMatchingFolders (String folderName){

    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Primary_Table + " WHERE " + Col_FolderName + " = " + folderName;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
 }
```

Error message I'm receiving

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: testFolder (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Folder_Table WHERE Col_FolderName = testFolder
```

Any assistance to help with the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the string value doesn't have quotes around it, so it is treated as a table name instead of a string. You should use a bound query argument to fix this. Bound arguments also prevent SQL injection attacks:

```
String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Primary_Table + " WHERE " + Col_FolderName + " = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, new String[]{folderName});
```

Note that you can do `"SELECT COUNT(*) as row_count" ...` to let the database engine count the number of records more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response, I've made the changes you've recommended. I knew I was missing some info from my code but completely forgot about how Strings are handled.

Comment: @user3403733 Strings in most languages need quotes around them. But here you have to be extra careful due to possible injection from user input. In general, you should avoid building a query string by directly concatenating any values that can come from the user.